# How can I configure network access for the Windows Phone emulator?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, fiddler, windows-phone-7-emulator

I'm trying to debug an application that is making a `WebRequest` synchronously, ie.:

```
HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://www.stackoverflow.com/")) as HttpWebRequest;

IAsyncResult res = req.BeginGetResponse(callback => { }, req);
while (!res.IsCompleted)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
}
// Doesn't matter what's here, as `res.IsCompleted` never returns true
```

This is just to check that some of the application logic is "right", but it's getting stuck, with the `IAsyncResult` never reporting itself as complete.

To check, things, I tried to use Internet Explorer on the emulator, but found that is unable to find *any* webpages (including the built in favourites), which makes me think that the emulator is trying to use a specific network interface on my laptop, but there doesn't seem to be any way to configure it, or which interface to use? I have a suspicion that it may be trying to use a VPN interface, or a virtual adaptor like the one for VirtualBox. So, how can I configure it? additionally, would you expect requests made by the emulator to show up in Fiddler?

For the record, `NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()` returns `true`;

**UPDATE:**

It appears that updating my graphics driver (and associated reboot) allowed the emulator to access the real network (or at least guess the right adapter); however, `res.IsCompleted` still doesn't report true (and Fiddler shows the request has completed), so I'm a little confuddled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a proxy? The Windows Phone emulator is tied to the currently active Internet Connection, as well as the proxy settings. Make sure those are set up correctly. Also, there might be a firewall blocking Internet access for XDE - check the settings too.

I would recommend getting [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). Attempt to [configure it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fiddler/archive/2010/10/15/fiddler-and-the-windows-phone-emulator.aspx) to capture emulator traffic and see what information you can get from there.

Comment: So, is Fiddler getting anything?

Comment: Since upgrading my video drivers, yes. Still unsure why `res.IsCompleted` never returns true on Windows Phone.

Comment: Your threading model is off. If you are waiting for the request to complete, might as well use the callback, that you left blank - it will get triggered when the request is completed.

Comment: That's what I've ended up doing - bit odd that res.IsCompleted does return true for "other platforms"